# Timeline with Awesome-CV

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, timeline, awesome-cv

I recently found an awesome [CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/moderncv-with-modern-timeline/prmmmvtvfxsn#.Wia1tzcxmUl) using timelines to show when what happened. I think this is an great example of goof visualization. Now I want to recreate this feature in Awesome-CV. Unfortunately I dont know how. I tried to use the "parallel"-package, but the entries were then overlapping to the side. Here is my MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Awesome Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/1/2016)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Claud D. Park (posquit0.bj@gmail.com) with modifications by 
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template must be compiled with XeLaTeX, the below lines will ensure this
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
%\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{left=7cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry
%\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parallel}


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

% Colors for text - uncomment and modify
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~·~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Education}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something else} % Degree
{University} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Another one} % Degree
{College} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}



%------------------------------------------------

\end{cventries}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Abilities}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cvskills}

%%------------------------------------------------
\end{cvskills}
\begin{cvletter}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\progtext}[8]{
\def\len{#1}
\def\he{#2}
\def\x{#3}
\def\y{#4}
\def\sepx{#5}
\def\sepy{#6}
\def\p{#7}
\def\text{#8}

\begin{scope}[shift={(\x*\len+\x*\sepx,-\y*\he-\y*\sepy)}]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (\len*\p,\he);
\fill [awesome] (0,0) rectangle (\len,\he)node [pos=.5,color=white] {\textbf{\text}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(\x*\len+\x*\sepx,-\y*\he-\y*\sepy)}]
\clip (\len*\p,0) rectangle (\len,\he);
\fill [awesome!70] (0,0) rectangle (\len,\he)node [pos=.5,color=white] {\textbf{\text}};
\end{scope}
}


\progtext{3}{0.5}{0}{0}{0.1}{0.2}{1}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{1}{0}{0.1}{0.2}{0.8}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{0}{1}{0.1}{0.2}{0.4}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{1}{1}{0.1}{0.2}{0.5}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{0}{2}{0.1}{0.2}{0.3}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{1}{2}{0.1}{0.2}{0.6}{Test}

\progtext{3}{0.5}{3}{0}{0.1}{0.2}{0.9}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{4}{0}{0.1}{0.2}{0.4}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{3}{1}{0.1}{0.2}{0.7}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{4}{1}{0.1}{0.2}{0.5}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{3}{2}{0.1}{0.2}{0.7}{Test}
\progtext{3}{0.5}{4}{2}{0.1}{0.2}{0.3}{Test}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{cvletter}





%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Here you see what the MWE looks like. I painted in what it should look like (blue lines). I also want section in which I can use the whole width of the document (red arrow).

Another idea would be to switch to ModernCV. Depending on how difficult it is.

[image]

Comment: To avoid digging through the details of awsome-cv.cls, you might try using the paracol package.  One column would hold the timelines and the other the normal CV stuff.

Comment: Did you try that out? I have the problem that location and date on the right go off the paper.

Comment: I can't even find awsome-cv.cls

Comment: You can download it here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm#.WibAVDcxmUl

Answer (score 4):

**You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality other people's documents which are tailored to their specific needs.  Therefore it is close to impossible to perform any modifications on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.**

Here is the best I can to for you in this case:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

\usepackage[firstyear=2000,lastyear=2025]{moderntimeline}
\colorlet{color1}{awesome}
\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{4cm}

\begin{document}

\cvsection{Education}

\begin{cventries}
  % ------------------------------------------------
  \tlcventry
  {2020}{2025}
  {Highschool} % Institution
  {Springfield} % Location
  {Something} % Degree
  { % Description(s) bullet points
    \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Test, Test, Test}
    \end{cvitems}
  }

  \tlcventry
  {2015}{2020}
  {University} % Institution
  {Springfield} % Location
  {Something else} % Degree
  { % Description(s) bullet points
    \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Test, Test, Test}
    \end{cvitems}
  }

  \tlcventry
  {2010}{2015}
  {College} % Institution
  {Springfield} % Location
  {Another one} % Degree
  { % Description(s) bullet points
    \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Test, Test, Test}
    \end{cvitems}
  }

  \tlcventry
  {2005}{2010}
  {Highschool} % Institution
  {Springfield} % Location
  {Something} % Degree
  { % Description(s) bullet points
    \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Test, Test, Test}
    \end{cvitems}
  }

  \tlcventry
  {2000}{2005}
  {Highschool} % Institution
  {Springfield} % Location
  {Something} % Degree
  { % Description(s) bullet points
    \begin{cvitems}
    \item {Test, Test, Test}
    \end{cvitems}
  }

\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. For the **bold** text and the moderntimeline package.

Comment: This is a nice solution. But I dont have that much space vertically and much more horizontally... But you are right, about what you said about templates :/