# Section text overlaps with awesome-cv and moderntimeline

Tags: moderntimeline, awesome-cv

I'm using `awesome-cv` and `moderntimeline` as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404727/timeline-with-awesome-cv), but I find that the heading of each CV entry tends to overlap with the text of the last entry. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2018]{moderntimeline}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}

% For moderntimeline.
\colorlet{color1}{awesome}  
\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{4cm}

\name{Dr Hannibal}{Lecter}
\address{Geneva, Switzerland}
\mobile{Don't call me}
\email{hannibal@favabeans.com}
\homepage{http://favabeans.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvheader
\makecvfooter{\today}{Dr Hannibal Lecter~~~~~~~~~.~~~~~~~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \tlcventry{2016}{2018}
    {Psychiatrist} 
    {Some Hospital} 
    {Geneva, Switzerland} 
    {} 
    {
      \begin{cvitems} 
        \item {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis vehicula pretium. Pellentesque faucibus nulla ipsum, sit amet tristique augue dignissim in. In lacinia urna quis dictum tempor. Quisque eros eros, rutrum quis tortor tempus, pharetra aliquam sapien.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \tlcventry{2007}{2016}
    {General Surgeon} 
    {Some Hospital} 
    {London, UK}
    {} 
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis vehicula pretium. Pellentesque faucibus nulla ipsum, sit amet tristique augue dignissim in. In lacinia urna quis dictum tempor. Quisque eros eros, rutrum quis tortor tempus, pharetra aliquam sapien.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

This can be partly solved by removing `moderntimeline`, or by forcing line breaks between entries, but even then the gap between some `cventry`s is smaller than it should be. For example here, the third CV entry is closer to the second than it ought to be:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should be extremely careful when using any so-called “template”: There are many things that the author(s) may not be aware of.

The [`moderntimeline`](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline) package, which is on CTAN, is designed for the [`moderncv`](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class, which is also on CTAN. However, the `awesome-cv` class is not available on CTAN (but is on GitHub).

The *main* cause of your problem is how the `cvitems` environment works (I don’t know if there are more causes). Indeed, in [`awesome-cv.cls`](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls) we find the following definition of `cvitems`:

```
% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
```

There are many things the `awesome-cv` author could improve on:

1. What’s the goal of using `nosep`, *then* `noitemsep`?
2. The local assignment `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` should be a global one.
3. BTW, changing `\parskip` within itemize lists has no effect, since lists use `\parsep` (and `\parsep` is already set to zero by either `nosep` or `noitemsep`).
4. I failed to see a reason why `\begin{justify}...\end{justify}` was used.
5. **Most importantly**, negative vertical spaces are applied to both the top *and* the bottom of `cvitems`. IMHO, these spaces should be declared by other means so that the users can change them. But then again, to quote [from @HenriMenke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404797/164314):

   > What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality other people’s documents which are tailored to their specific needs.

Let’s change the `\vspace{-4.0mm}` after `\end{justify}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2018]{moderntimeline}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}

% For moderntimeline.
\colorlet{color1}{awesome}  
\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{4cm}

% Let's customize here
\renewenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  %\vspace{-4.0mm}
  \vspace{4.0mm}
}

\name{Dr Hannibal}{Lecter}
\address{Geneva, Switzerland}
\mobile{Don't call me}
\email{hannibal@favabeans.com}
\homepage{http://favabeans.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvheader
\makecvfooter{\today}{Dr Hannibal Lecter~~~~~~~~~.~~~~~~~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \tlcventry{2016}{2018}
    {Psychiatrist} 
    {Some Hospital} 
    {Geneva, Switzerland} 
    {} 
    {%
      \begin{cvitems} 
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis vehicula pretium. Pellentesque faucibus nulla ipsum, sit amet tristique augue dignissim in. In lacinia urna quis dictum tempor. Quisque eros eros, rutrum quis tortor tempus, pharetra aliquam sapien.
      \end{cvitems}%
    }

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \tlcventry{2007}{2016}
    {General Surgeon} 
    {Some Hospital} 
    {London, UK}
    {} 
    {%
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis vehicula pretium. Pellentesque faucibus nulla ipsum, sit amet tristique augue dignissim in. In lacinia urna quis dictum tempor. Quisque eros eros, rutrum quis tortor tempus, pharetra aliquam sapien.
      \end{cvitems}%
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

[image: cv]

Note the `%`’s I added just before each `\begin{cvitems}` and just after each `\end{cvitems}`. I also removed the unnecessary braces around “Lorem ipsum…” and added an empty line between the two `\tlcventry`’s.